# Testing React Component with Jest and Enzyme. Error: Can't read property of map is undefined

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

So i haven't been able to get the todos passed down from the parent component nor have i been able to successfully set them myself.  I'm not trying to test anything in particular at this point.  Just that the component 'exists' without error

Component code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import TodoItem from './TodoItem';

class TodoList extends Component {
    renderTodos = () => {
        const { todos } = this.props;
        return todos.map(todo => {
            return <TodoItem key={todo.id} {...todo} />;
        });
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderTodos()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TodoList;
```

Test code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import TodoList from './TodoList';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';

describe(TodoList, () => {
    const todos = [
        {
            id: 1,
            text: 'Walk the walk'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            text: 'Talk the talk'
        }
    ];
    const component = shallow(<TodoList todos={todos} />);

    it('should exist', () => {
        const component = renderer.create(<TodoList />);
        const tree = component.toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

Please help.  New to Jest and pretty new to testing in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a shallow instance of your component you need to pass the props which you are using without conditional check in your component

```
const component = shallow(<TodoList todos={[]}/>);
```

and

```
const component = renderer.create(<TodoList todos={[]}/>);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Yes, i believe i tried that.  My updated code is above now.  I tried this before but i still received a 'cannot read property 'map' of undefined' error.  Maybe i'm misunderstanding your suggestion.

Comment: The prop that you need is `todos` and not `Todos`

Comment: by bad.  It was todos=(todos} in my code.  Still 'cannot read property 'map' of undefined'

Comment: Ohhh, that's because you recreate the snapshot, renderer.create in which you haven't passed it

Comment: Yes, that's it.  Thanks!  I also just caught that but wasn't sure if that was the needed or a round  about way of fixing the issue.  Thank you for you help!